# prettier extension not Working in VS_Code...?

Tags: prettier-eslint

i installed the pritter extension and it doesn't work not in any language like javaScript and not in the react js project...?

Every time when i select the prettier to formate the code it doesn't do anyThing and through the error and shows a warning sign at the status bar of the VsCode.
See the attached picture.

i tried the Chat gpt and youtube videos..But it doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCRa5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Install prettier in your project

*npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier* or
*yarn add --dev --exact prettier*

also, add config file in root directory

.prettierrc

example of my config:

```
{   "semi": true,   "trailingComma": "all",   "singleQuote": true,   "printWidth": 80,   "tabWidth": 2 }
```